# What kind of voice is "滄桑的聲音" describing?

Tags: translation

I believe that "滄桑" is "huge changes", but how can a voice be described as that?

With some googling, I am guessing (pure guessing) that "滄桑" means "aged/old", but how did "huge changes" turn into that?

Comment: iciba：滄桑 （见“沧海桑田”） 
沧桑的声音："the voice of 
    vicissitudes, vicissitudes of life,
    great changes" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be exact, `沧桑` doesn't just mean `aged/old`.

`沧桑` comes from the idiom `沧海桑田`, as you understand, it means `huge changes (in a long time)`. And `沧桑的声音` means a kind of voice, which can make you feel that he/she has experienced many things changed, e.g. many vicissitudes of life.